# SAS: Unable to add variable to data set

Tags: sas, dataset

I have a data set and am trying to add four new variables using the existing ones. I keep getting an error that says the code is incomplete. I'm having trouble seeing where it is incomplete. How do I fix this?

```
data dataset;
 input  ID $
        Height 
        Weight 
        SBP 
        DBP 
        WtKg         = Weight/2.2;
        HtCm         =  Height/2.4;
        AveBP        = DBP + (SBP - DBP)/3;
        HtPolynomial = (2*Height)**2 + (1.5*Height)**3;
 
datalines;
001 68 150 110 70
002 73 240 150 90
003 62 101 120 80
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not end your `input` statement with a semicolon. `input` reads variables from external data (in this case, in-line data with the `datalines` statement). New variables are not created within `input` in the way you've specified.

Use `input` to read in the five variables of your data. After that, create new variables based on those five read-in variables:

```
data dataset;
    input  ID $
           Height 
           Weight 
           SBP 
           DBP
    ; 

    WtKg         = Weight/2.2;
    HtCm         = Height/2.4;
    AveBP        = DBP + (SBP - DBP)/3;
    HtPolynomial = (2*Height)**2 + (1.5*Height)**3;
 
    datalines;
001 68 150 110 70
002 73 240 150 90
003 62 101 120 80
;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you!  It has been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Correcting 2 errors should fix this:

1. Add a semicolon after the last field being read in from the datalines, which is DBP.
2. (A previous version of this question used the ^ symbol for exponents.) Instead of ^ to raise to the power of something, use **

   For reference, SAS arithmetic operators are described [here](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/z0780367.htm).

After making the 2 corrections above I ran the revised code below without any errors.

```
data dataset;
 input  ID $
        Height 
        Weight 
        SBP 
        DBP; 
        WtKg         = Weight/2.2;
        HtCm         =  Height/2.4;
        AveBP        = DBP + (SBP - DBP)/3;
        HtPolynomial = (2*Height)**2 + (1.5*Height)**3;
 
datalines;
001 68 150 110 70
002 73 240 150 90
003 62 101 120 80
run;
```